# AngularJS: "TypeError: undefined is not a function" with routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to track down a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" error in AngularJS. If you have any ideas, or even better, **suggestions on how to debug something like this**, I'd appreciate it. Note that this is very similar to the code I'm working on, but not exactly the same (although it still has the same errors when run).

**trace:**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at update (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular-route.js:838:13)
    at Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:11803:28)
    at http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular-route.js:549:26
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:10549:81)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:10549:81)
    at http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:10635:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:11528:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:11373:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:11634:24)
    at done (http://localhost:63342/Channels/vendor/angular.js:7635:45)
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="channelsApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

<!--App Scripts-->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var channelsApp = angular.module('channelsApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'channelsControllers'
]);

channelsApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/new', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/test.html',
                controller: 'CreateChannelCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/new'
            });
}]);
```

**controllers.js:**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var channelsControllers = angular.module('channelsControllers', []);

channelsControllers.controller("CreateChannelCtrl", ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        console.log("Success!");
    }]);
```

**test.html**

```
<div>This is a test.</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using an outdated AngularJS version causes this bug.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to be the issue. Stupid question on my part, really.

Answer (score 3):

I used the same code and it works for me. There might be some issue with the library. Update your angular library. Please let me know if you want my code.

And I don't think that there is some issue with
 `<script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>`, since in the tutorial of AngularJS on their site, they too have included app.js before controller.js. 
And I guess its logical since in javascript and in 'strict mode' too you call a function then you can define it;

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
'use strict';
callMe(0);
function callMe(a){alert(a)}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code works fine.

Please correct me if I am wrong at any point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since `channelsApp` depends on `channelsControllers`

```
var channelsApp = angular.module('channelsApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'channelsControllers'
]);
```

You have to reverse the scripts like this:

```
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The possible problem is you use different versions of angular.js and angular-route.js. As this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NM4YW40Wphj7eDmwhLxk?p=preview) shows, when their versions are different, there is error.

If you use the same versions, like this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TK4el0YviY6aPrqefoQp?p=preview), it works.

**Note**: ngRoute is moved into its own module since version 1.2. In version 1.0, ngRoute is in the core. For more information: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngroute-has-been-moved-into-its-own-module

Comment: I made a new project from scratch with the code from above and it works properly with either order. This also means that the problem lies somewhere else. :(

Comment: Looks like swapping out the local files I had for the most up-to-date versions on the server fixed the issue.

Comment: @Salem: I still recommend that you should define the scripts order like this to avoid any problems caused by injecting an instance from `channelsControllers` to `channelsApp`

Comment: That's probably a safe change to make. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Salem: the problem is probably you're using different versions of angular.js and angular-route.js. They are not compatible with each other. Check my DEMOs

Comment: I was testing a sub module and the parent included all of the dependencies in the app itself but not in the isolated test.  This solved it!